# NullReferenceException on a conditional null check

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

For Following lines of code:

```
Class1 Obj1 = GetObjByID(ID); 
if (Obj1!= null) 
{ 
     Obj1.IsAgentReserved = true; // causing exception here
     Obj2.EstDeviceID = Obj1.Extension; 
}
```

I have exception "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at Obj1.IsAgentReserved = true;, Although I have place null check before this.

What could be the possible reasons? This occurs occasionally and i can not reproduce it.

I have checked following things: 
1. != operator is not overloaded 
2. Stacktrace is seems correct to me  
3. Present version of the code matches the stacktrace

Comment: Is `IsAgentReserved` a property? If yes, what does the code of the setter look like?

Comment: If `Obj1` actually null after the exception is thrown? It must be some other object causing the exception.

Comment: does `GetObjByID(ID);` return an object of class `Class1`?

Comment: Is this actual code?  Do you really have a class called "Class1"?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in a multithreaded application where another thread has deleted the object between your !null check and it's use.

Comment: Not in this case; as Obj1 is a local variable, it will be impossible for other threads to change it to null.

Comment: It can't set the variables value to null but it can destroy the object it is pointing to (which might very well be a shared thing). And thus invalidating the reference.

Comment: I assume this is C#, where only the garbage collector destroys objects - which it won't do while a local variable refers to that object

Comment: Yes, Jonas you are right. Its C# and variable should not be destroyed while I have its refrence.

Comment: @m abrar Retagged for you, remember to provide good tags, as it increases the likelihood that resident C# experts will see your question :-)